# The method addAnnotatedClass(Class<demo>) is undefined for the type Configuration

Tags: hibernate-annotations

The method addAnnotatedClass(Class) is undefined for the type Configuration

I am trying to insert data into data base using Hibernate in my Dynamic web project . Annotations are used instead of XML file. But i am getting a compilation error "The method addAnnotatedClass(Class) is undefined for the type Configuration" .How will i solve it ?

```
package pak;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SessionFactory factory= new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").addAnnotatedClass(demo.class).buildSessionFactory();
        Session session=factory.getCurrentSession();

        try{
            demo obj=new demo("name1","name2","name3");
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(obj);          
            session.getTransaction().commit();


        }finally{
            factory.close();
        }
    }

}
```

i want to know that, what is the cause  compilation error "The method addAnnotatedClass(Class) is undefined for the type Configuration" and how to solve it

Comment: Probably there's something else you're doing wrong. The code above compiled here when I tested it.

Comment: when i change    SessionFactory factory= new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").addAnnotatedClass(demo.class).buildSessionFactory();   to
        Session session=factory.getCurrentSession();  SessionFactory factory= new AnnotationConfiguration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").addAnnotatedClass(demo.class).buildSessionFactory();
        Session session=factory.getCurrentSession();  compilation error solved . Thanku for ur valuable time spend to solve my quey .thankuu ..

Comment: Can any one give an example or a step by step guidance to enter data into data base using hibernate annotation in java project (not in Maven)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have forgotten to Annotate the demo class that you want to import there:

You should declare Annotations before you use that class.

[image]